# Use PowerShell to stop-process, can i bypass confirm?

Tags: powershell, windows-services, powershell-cmdlet

I'm a powershell newbie, but I often find myself starting and stopping a small group of services when I'm debugging some code. In Powershell I can easily stop the processes using a wildcard but it makes me confirm. There is a -confirm parameter, but I must not be using it correctly?

```
`Stop-Process -ProcessName alcore.* -Confirm`
```

Can I bypass the confirm and just stop the process?

Thanks for any help,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
stop-process -ProcessName alcore.* -Force
```

From `get-help stop-process`:

> On Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, to stop a process
>   that is not owned by the current user,
>   you must start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.  Also,
>   you are prompted for confirmation
>   unless you use the Force parameter.

Answer (score 3):

-Confirm:$false

Comment: actually this doesn't work:
```[server]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> Stop-Process -Name python -Confirm:$false```
still prompts me:
```Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform the Stop-Process operation on the following item: python(248)?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "Y"): 
```

Comment: Right. This _should_ work, but it doesn't. You have to pass `-Force`. Not sure if this is a bug or intended.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want it to do a confirmation then don't use the -confirm option but instead the -force.  Doing this will cause the process to be stopped without any user confirmation.

> kill -force outlook

Answer (score 3):

-Confirm:$false is correct and works for all PS confirmation prompts.

Comment: exemple :  Stop-Process -d 11048 -Confirm:$false